# Type-checking tagged pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Last week I was playing with a threaded suffix tree. The tree is too large to use recursion for traversal, and I have solved the problem in various ways before--using explicit stacks, continuations, you name it--and this time I added threaded pointers from all nodes, so I could traverse the tree without any additional allocation along the way.

The basic structure of nodes is

```c
struct node
{
    // more data here...
    struct node *child;
    tagged_ptr sibling;
};
```

where `tagged_ptr` is a pointer to `struct node` but with the lowest bit used to indicate whether it is pointing at a true sibling or pointing up to a sibling of an ancestor, where the traversal would go after traversing a sub-tree.

The idea is that you can traverse a (sub-)tree just following either `child` or `sibling` pointers:

```c
static inline struct node *next(struct node *n)
{
    return n->child ? n->child : tp_pointer(n->sibling);
}

...
    struct node *sentinel = tp_pointer(n->sibling);
    for (; n != sentinel; n = next(n))
        // do stuff wit n
```

(the sentinel is where you return to after seeing the entire subtree of `n`), or you can traverse just the children of a node, when searching down the tree, with

```c
static inline struct node *next_sibling(struct node *n)
{
    return tp_is_taggged(n->sibling) ? 0 : tp_pointer(n->sibling);
}

...

    for (struct node *child = n->child;
         child;
         child = next_sibling(child))
        // do something with child...
```

For this idea, I need to be able to distinguish between true sibling pointers and threaded pointers. At least I think so, I haven't figured out how to recognise when I am through the true children otherwise.

That is where the tagged pointers come in. The alignment of `struct node` is higher than one

```c
_Static_assert(_Alignof(struct node) > 1,
               "Nodes must have alignment higher than one.");
```

so the least significant bit is free, and I can exploit that. I've used that a couple of times before, and it isn't too difficult to get a tagged pointer. It could be something like this:

```c
typedef uintptr_t tagged_ptr;
static inline tagged_ptr tp_set(tagged_ptr tp)        { return tp | 1; }
static inline tagged_ptr tp_unset(tagged_ptr tp)      { return tp & ~1; }
static inline void *     tp_pointer(tagged_ptr tp)    { return (void *)tp_unset(tp); }
static inline bool       tp_is_taggged(tagged_ptr tp) { return tp & 1; }
static inline tagged_ptr tag_ptr(void *ptr, bool tag) { return (tagged_ptr)ptr | tag; }
```

It just bothers me that I am throwing away all type information with this approach. I use the type `uintptr_t` instead of `struct node *` so I don't accidentally follow a pointer with a tag, but that is as far as type safety goes. Nothing will prevent me from setting a tagged pointer to `struct node *` two a pointer to `int *`.

Of course, in this application it isn't much of an issue. There is only one kind of tagged pointers and I can make sure to cast to the right type. I need some casting anyway to get the bits in the pointer. But I was wondering how far you could get with a generic tagged pointer, if you wanted more type safety.

I can get parts of the way. I can define tagged pointers that remember their type, and I can ensure that you only assign the right kind of pointers to them. Using a union of a pointer and `uintptr_t`, I make sure that you cannot assign a pointer of the wrong time:

```c
#define tagged_ptr(T)                                            \
    _Static_assert(sizeof(T *) == sizeof(uintptr_t),             \
                   "Pointer type must match size of uintptr_t"); \
    union {                                                      \
        T *ptr;                                                  \
        uintptr_t bits;                                          \
    }

#define tp_set(TP, P, TAG)      \
    do                          \
    {                           \
        (TP).ptr = P;           \
        (TP).bits |= ((TAG)&1); \
    } while (0)

#define tp_tag(TP) \
    ((TP).bits & 1)
```

Now you can declare tagged pointers of different types and you can assign to them and tag them, but only with the right type of pointers.

```c
struct foo
{
    int a, b;
    tagged_ptr(struct foo) t;
};
_Static_assert(_Alignof(struct foo) > 1,
               "Least significant bit must be free for tags.");
_Static_assert(_Alignof(int) > 1,
               "Least significant bit must be free for tags.");

...


    struct foo *x = malloc(sizeof *x);
    tp_set(x->t, x, 1);
    assert(tp_tag(x->t) == 1);

    int i = 42;
    tagged_ptr(int) tip;
    tp_set(tip, &i, 0);
    assert(tp_tag(tip) == 0);

    //tp_set(x->t, &i, 0); // error
    //tp_set(tip, x, 0);   // error
```

However, I cannot get the pointer back without using compiler extensions.

If I have `__typeof__` I could do this:

```c
#define tp_ptr(TP) \
    ((__typeof__((TP).ptr))((TP).bits & ~1))
```

It gets the type from the tagged pointer and returns that, thus keeping the type-checker in the loop.

If I don't have `__typeof__` but I have GCC's statement expressions I can provide the type, create a new tagged pointer where I can mask the bits out, check the type of the pointer, mask, and return:

```c
#define tp_ptr(T, TP)                        \
    ({ tagged_ptr(T) tp;                     \
       tp.ptr = (TP).ptr;  /* checks type */ \
       tp.bits &= ~1;                        \
       tp.ptr; })
```

Is there a more portable way to get the type information preserved when extracting the pointer, i.e. a way to mask the last bit out without throwing the type information away completely? I have to cast to get the bits, of course, but I can preserve the type and cast back with the two approaches above. They just require compiler extensions, so they are not standard compliant.

I realise that it is a bit silly to go for standard C solutions here, considering that the second I start fiddling with the bits in a pointer I have left portability and entered implementation/undefined behaviour, but using the low bit in this way is likely to work more places than compiler extensions will, and I am curious if there is a way to do it.

I don't strictly need it, it just bothers me that I don't know how to do it. I would love either to know that it cannot be done, or know how to do it. Either will suit me equally well. Not knowing bothers me.

Comment: GCC has `typeof`, so I'd suggest just use `typeof` if the compiler supports it, and accept that the other compilers have weaker type checking.  (Use `void *` in those compilers.)  If you compile your code in GCC once in a while, type errors will get caught then.

Comment: I know typeof solves the problem. It is the first solution after all (just with __typeof__ instead of typeof since it is the same on gcc but also works with clang). I can easily do this with compiler extensions. The question is if it can be done without. That is what I can’t readily figure out.

Comment: But yeah, I would catch it as long as I always compile with gcc on commit. Regardless of what other compilers are used.

Answer (score 0):

As it usually is, you come up with a solution *right after* you ask...

This will work, and in standard C:

```c
#define tp_ptr(T, TP) \
    ((T *)0 == (TP).ptr, (T *)((TP).bits & ~1))
```

I don't need statement expressions if I don't need new variables, and I can simply check the type of the pointer against a NULL pointer of the desired type before I returned the casted manipulated bits in a comma expression.

The `((T *)) == (TP).ptr)` expression does the type-checking. After I have made sure that `T` is the right type, I can return a pointer of that type.

I don't use the result of the comparison, so it doesn't matter if I have a NULL pointer or not, and I would expect any compiler to optimise the comparison away.